# SSD configure on linux

Tags: linux, windows-10, ssd, centos, dvd

I changed my Alienware 17 R1 DVD drive to an SSD disk of 1000 GB.On windows 10 i can
see the disk as on normal, however,on Centos 7 installed on VMware I could not access the same
disk.
Any help on this  matter is highly appreciated?

Comment: You can install a VMware machine on any attached disk . Did you point it to the SSD?  Use File Explorer to see where the VM folder is located.

Comment: i have Wmware instaled on my primary disk with centos 7 as operating system, my concern is i could not see the disk installed on the dvd drive on when running centos 7

Comment: I am betting that you need to share the disk with your virtual operating system.  You don't automatically get access.  You need the VMWare tools installed, then go to VM settings.. "shared folders".. and ADD the drive you want to be exposed.

Comment: exactly what i did but centos 7 does not see the disk , i still even using shared folder cant access the disk